# Swap using a pointer without referring the array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

so i need to swap row 2 and row 3 of my array. There is a catch our professor had us use a one dimensional array and use a pointer instead of a 2d array. We cannot reference the array only the pointer. I have no idea how to do this.

```
int numbers[25] = { 1,3,5,7,9 , -2,-4,-6, -8, -10 , 3,3,3,3,3 , 55, 77, 99, 22, 33, -15, -250, -350, -450, -550 };
```

this array is supposed to look like this:

```
 1     3     5     7     9 
   -2    -4    -6    -8   -10   // i need to swap this row
    3     3     3     3     3   // for this row
   55    77    99    22    33 
  -15  -250  -350  -450  -550 

This is how i need to print it
  1     3     5     7     9 
  3     3     3     3     3
 -2    -4    -6    -8   -10  
   55    77    99    22    33 
  -15  -250  -350  -450  -550
```

Note: this is not my whole HW assignment is just where i am stuck.

Comment: First try printing all elements using pointer arithmatic.

Comment: Start by inserting new lines and making that easily readable. What do you mean by swapping?

Comment: Do you know how to reference a "one dimensional" array as it was "two dimensional"? If not then start there. When (or if) you know that, then do you know to swap rows in a "real" 2d array? Then learn that as well. Once you know both of these things, you should be able to combine that knowledge.

Comment: So you aren't allowed to use for example `numbers[i]`, correct?

Comment: Also remember that for any pointer *or* array `p` and index `i` the expressions `p[i]` is equal to `*(p + i)`. That means even if you have a pointer then doing `p[i]` is valid pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Please be more specific about the _use a pointer instead of a 2d array_ and the _we cannot reference the array only the pointer_ parts.

Comment: ... and are you sure you are asking about C++ and not C?

Comment: Are you sure that your professor didn't mean a one-dimensional array of pointers?

Answer (score 5):

Why not try something like:

```
constexpr std::size_t rowLength = 5u;
const auto beginRow2 = std::begin(numbers) + (rowLength * 2);
const auto endRow2 = std::begin(numbers) + (rowLength * 3);
const auto beginRow3 = std::begin(numbers) + (rowLength * 3);
std::swap_ranges(beginRow2, endRow2, beginRow3);
```

This is idiomatic C++ and can easily be adapted to provide a generic function that accepts a 1-dimensional container, a row-length and the two rows to swap.

Answer (score -1):

Just define a temporary array:

```
int tmp_row[5];
```

Save the third row:

```
int bytes = sizeof(tmp_row);

memcpy(tmp_row, &numbers[10], bytes);
```

Then fill in the second and third rows appropriately:

```
memcpy(&numbers[10], &numbers[5], bytes);
memcpy(&numbers[5], tmp_row, bytes);
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use std::copy/copy_n instead of memcpy, which is a C relict.

Comment: The question is for a beginner programming course: they encourage judicious usage of C-style C++.

Comment: C-style C++ is very rarely judicious.

Comment: @nefas Looks like I was using the word wrong. I suppose "they fervently encourage" would have been more accurate.

Comment: Sorry, I understood that you thought that it was better to use C-style C++.